# Is there an elegant way of concatenating an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i have an array, containing arrays inside:

```
var arr = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7],
    [8,9,0]
];
```

What's the most elegant way to extract

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I can make it like:

```
var final = [];
params.forEach(function(bulk){
    final = final.concat(bulk);
});
```

but was looking for something more elegant / pretty

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an Array of Arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7],
    [8,9,0]
]);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Note that you can further reduce it to `[].concat.apply` but might have a cost of creation of an extra (empty) array (I guess this is browser implementation-dependent).

Comment: i have no idea why someone downvoted you. this is exactly what i'm looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
console.log([].concat.apply([], arr));
```

If array has **only numbers** you also can use this

```
arr.toString().split(',').map(Number);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/malemu/2/edit?js,console)